# Finding out which function, model or script created a variable in a workspace

Tags: matlab, simulink, workspace

I'm using a simulationenvironment in matlab that's consisting of multiple scripts, functions and simulink models. Now I want to find out which of These created a specific variable in my Base-Workspace. Is there a way of finding this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot trace back how a variable was created, but you may find the possible *candidates* that might create the variable.

If you know the name of the variable (let's say is 'my_var'), the use the 'Find files...' from the Edit menu (the usual key biding is [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[F]) to look into all files that containing the text `my_var`. Do not forget to configure the containing folder to include other paths than the current one, if you're calling some package/toolbox-level scripts.

Comment: It took me a couple of steps to find what I was looking for, but after all this solved my problem. Thank you!
EDIT: In my case the variable was created in a script that was loaded in the InitFcn of a simulink-model. In case someone has the same problem, you might want to check that.